Manual Migration of an existing DB to MongoEngine doesn't populate fields
I have an existing database of data that I want to use with MongoEngine. I updated the class as follows:
class World(Document):
    user = ReferenceAttr(choices=["User"], required=True)
    journal = ReferenceAttr(choices=[Journal])
    name = StringAttr()
    history = StringAttr()
    last_updated = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

The I manually massaged the DB entries to fit into MongoEngine's schema. Below is an example of the manual migration result in the DB:
    _id: ObjectId('65ac20ed012362b1d87ce645'),
    _cls: 'World',
    name: 'Red Sun',
    history: '',
    journal: {
        _cls: 'Journal',
        _ref: DBRef('journal', '65ba6fbe37d921ede3686388')
    },
    user: {
        _cls: 'User',
        _ref: DBRef('user', '65ac20e3012362b1d87ce63f')
    },
    last_updated: ISODate('2024-08-19T14:34:56.874Z')

When I do print(cls.objects.all()), I get a object for each entry, which seems correct so far:
[<World: World object>, <World: World object>, <World: World object>, <World: World object>, <World: World object>, <World: World object>, <World: World object>, <World: World object>]

However, printing [vars(o) for o in cls.objects.all()] results in {}s.
And when I try to access the objects attributes, such as obj.name, I get:
   instance = <World: World object>, owner = <class 'models.world.World'>

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        """Descriptor for retrieving a value from a field in a document."""
        if instance is None:
            # Document class being used rather than a document object
            return self
    
        # Get value from document instance if available
>       return instance._data.get(self.name)
E       AttributeError: 'World' object has no attribute '_data'. Did you mean: '_delta'?

I have traced through the code and cannot figure out why it is not populating the values. Anyone have any ideas?
From what I can tell, all Document objects should have a default _data attribute, so I don't know why the object has nothing in it.

why you are use ReferenceAttr ?
please use ReferenceField for World class
from mongoengine import *
from datetime import datetime

class World(Document):
    user = ReferenceField('User', required=True)  #  You can use it like this, but because I don't have the user class, I wrote it as a string ReferenceField(User, required=True) 
    journal = ReferenceField('Journal')
    name = StringField()
    history = StringField()
    last_updated = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

example usage :
world = World.objects.first()
print(world.name)

